# Is JMS queue synchronized between producers and consumers?. How does it handle the queue status between producer and consumers?

Tags: java, jms, p2p, producer-consumer

Is JMS queue synchronized between producers and consumers?. How does it maintain the queue status between producer and consumers? If it is, then does that mean that producer is blocked till the consumer exits out of the receive method?

Comment: Does it internally use Michael-Scott nonblocking queue?

Comment: Does it use ConcurrentLinkedQueue?

Comment: You keep refering to "it", but there is no it. JMS is a specification only, it doesn't do anything on its own. You can't download "jms.jar" and run it. There are many "its" which each have their own implementation of a queue. The wiki has a good number of example "its": http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Message_Service

Comment: Thanks. I understand that JMS is a specification. My question was more towards the implementation details of JMS and how the queue is able to manage non blocking producers and consumers.

Comment: in other words you are interested in learning the theory behind a message queue so you may implement one yourself, and you just picked JMS as an example to try and illustrate what you are talking about?

Comment: Well then change your question and actually reflect that in there. Right now you're making it look like you're asking specifically about JMS.

Answer (score 0):

The queue is not synchronized; the whole point of a queue is to permit asynchronous task submission, so the producer can go on to do other things while the task is awaiting handling.  The producer is not blocked while consumers are receiving in any useful JMS implementation.

Comment: Thanks. But my question was how the queue maintains the state when both producers and consumers are operating on it at the same time. As per my understanding only one operation can be performed on the queue and  other thread has to wait till that operation is complete. Does it use non blocking algorithm?. If so how does it handle it.

Comment: Does it use Michael-Scott nonblocking queue?

Comment: JMS provides interfaces only; the specific algorithms used depend on which third party JMS implementation you decide to use.  However, I've never seen an implementation that blocks the producer while the consumer is receiving.

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of queuing is to ensure no one gets blocked, neither producer nor consumer. A consumer may wait for messages but that does not block a producer who wants to put messages. I am unaware if any queuing implementation is using Michael-Scott algorithm but I would not worry about implementation details for all practical purposes as long as an implementation meets my messaging requirements.